# How can I tell if a form was displayed with ShowDialog?

Tags: .net, winforms, modal-dialog

I'm developing a custom control that doesn't inherit from Button.
I want to implement a functionality similar to the DialogResult from the standard button, setting the FormParent.DialogResult to the specified value on PerformClick and then closing it.

However, I need to know if the form has been shown with ShowDialog instead of Show (i.e., if it's a modal window).

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Form.Modal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.form.modal.aspx) property, eg:

```
if(this.Modal)
    Debug.WriteLine("Hooray, I am a modal form");
```